# How to start Inets httpd server?

Tags: erlang, inets

I try to start Inets httpd server and have some documents in the `document_root`, but I can not start up the server. How can I start it?

This is the config I start it with:

```
>{ok, Pid} = inets:start(httpd, [{port, 8070}, {server_name, "myhttpd"},
>{server_root, "/Users/jonas/code"},
>{document_root, "/Users/jonas/code/mydocs"},
>{bind_address, "localhost"}]).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error, inets_not_started}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get more information about error when starting Inets httpd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594053/how-to-get-more-information-about-error-when-starting-inets-httpd) (the OP is actually the same for both).

Comment: @toraritte if you read the questions, they are different. One is about "how to start" the other is about "how to get error info when start fails"

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222558/how-to-start-inets-httpd-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first call `inets:start/0`.

Comment: Probably better way of starting applications is using application:start(Application) - it will take care of some generic stuff.

Comment: @Anton: Do you have any example how I can start Inets httpd with that method?

Comment: @Jonas httpd is not application, httpd is a service - your code for starting *httpd service* is correct. My comment was about starting *application* and application is inets (in this case).

Comment: @AntonKoval': Yes, I know that, but how should I start `Inets` as you describe? `application:start(Inets).` does not work, any example?

Comment: @Jonas  > application:start(inets).