# How to get more information about error when starting Inets httpd?

Tags: erlang, inets

I started Inets http with:

```
> inets:start(httpd, [{port, 8060}, {server_name, "myserver"},
> {server_root, "/Users/jonas/code"},                         
> {document_root, "/Users/jonas/code/mydocs"},             
> {bind_address, {192, 168, 2, 5}}]).                         
{error,inets_not_started}
```

so the only error information I have is `{error,inets_not_started}`. Is there any way I can get more information on what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to solve your problem just start [inets](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html) application (error reason indicates it is not started) by:

```
inets:start().
```

Second, in general starting [SASL application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html) improves a bit readability of Erlang/OTP errors/crashes - but it is not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `inets:start/0` first. See [the inets documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> start(Service, ServiceConfig, How) -> {ok, Pid} | {error, Reason}

```
Dynamically starts an inets service after the inets application has been started.
```

So you need call this function first.

> start() ->
>   start(Type) -> ok | {error, Reason}

Types:
Type = permanent | transient | temporary

```
 Starts the Inets application.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question because of the unfortunate overloading of the [`inets:start/[0,1,2,3]`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html) function and the [`httpc` documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) isn't very clear that starting `inets` will automatically start the `httpc` service as well.

<sup>Especially when on simply jumps to the [HTTP CLIENT SERVICE START/STOP](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#http-client-service-start-stop) section to get started quickly, thus missing the note in [the module description](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#description).</sup>

- [`inets:start/[0,1]`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html#start-0) starts the `inets` application itself **and** the `httpc` service with the default profile called `default` (this is only documented in [`httpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html)).
- [`inets:start/[2,3]`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html#start-1) (which should be called **`start_service`**) starts one of the services that can run atop `inets` (viz. `ftpc`, `tftp`, `httpc`, `httpd`) **once the `inets` application has already started**.

> `start() ->`
> `start(Type) -> ok | {error, Reason}`
>
> Starts the Inets application.

> `start(Service, ServiceConfig) -> {ok, Pid} | {error, Reason}`
> `start(Service, ServiceConfig, How) -> {ok, Pid} | {error, Reason}`
>
> Dynamically starts an Inets service **after
> the Inets application has been started**
>     (with [`inets:start/[0,1]`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html#start-0)).

---

#### Note regarding `httpc`

From the top of the [`httpc` module documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html):

> When starting the Inets application, a manager process for the default profile is started. The functions in this API that do not explicitly use a profile accesses the default profile.

That is, the `httpc` service will automatically get started using the default profile called `default`.

```
1> inets:start().
ok
2> httpc:get_options(all, default).
{ok,[{proxy,{undefined,[]}},
     {https_proxy,{undefined,[]}},
     {pipeline_timeout,0},
     {max_pipeline_length,2},
     {max_keep_alive_length,5},
     {keep_alive_timeout,120000},
     {max_sessions,2},
     {cookies,disabled},
     {verbose,false},
     {ipfamily,inet},
     {ip,default},
     {port,default},
     {socket_opts,[]},
     {unix_socket,undefined}]}
3>
3> inets:start(httpc, [{profile, lofa}]).
{ok,<0.95.0>}
4>
5> httpc:get_options(all, default).
{ok,[...]}
6> httpc:get_options(all, lofa).
{ok,[...]}
```

Interestingly, when using a non-existing profile, the error message is `inets_not_started`:

```
7> httpc:get_options(all, balabab).
{error,inets_not_started}
```